# Clicking on empty space triggers a layout to be selected (Included Gif)

Tags: android

Some unexpected behavior is occurring when I set my parent layout with clickable="true"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
```

When I click on empty space with no set listeners, it causes one of my layouts to be selected. Does anyone know why? This only happens when I set clickable="true" on my fragment's parentlayout because without it, the click goes through to the fragment below.

View of 23 people are going:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragevent_rl_peoplegoing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragevent_cl_hostedby"
    android:background="@drawable/settings_pressed_color"/>
```

**Here is a gif of the issue:**

https://i.imgur.com/hlFjZSw.mp4

Answer (score 0):

For that "**23 people are going**" view at the bottom, do you have this attribute defined?

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

Or have you called the corresponding `setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true)` method on it?

If so, remove those.

Having this attribute set (or setting it in code) will mean that when the parent `RelativeLayout` is in a "clicked" or "pressed" state, so is the child, as far as drawing is concerned. That would explain why it only happens when you set `clickable="true"` on the RelativeLayout: without that attribute, the parent never has a pressed state, so there's nothing for the child to inherit.

Comment: Don't have either of those on my view

Comment: What happens if you explicitly define them to be turned off (`duplicateParentState="false"` or `setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(false)`)? Does the problem still happen?

Comment: Yes it still happens

Comment: Fair enough. Guess it's something else :)

Comment: extremely weird. I didn't add an onClickListener to the last layout(23 people are going) and once I added it, the issue went away. I tested it by also removing the listener on the third layout(Hosted by) and it would bounce between the two.  https://i.imgur.com/iRDqyIz.mp4